# How do I get gloss/matte control through an image texture?

Tags: shaders

First ever material I'm trying to make and can't find what I need online. I created a black and white specular map, and a normal map in photoshop.I found out how to invert the normal using the invert node, but am not getting any results with the specular map wherever I put it. I watched chocofur's glossy shader video, but when I plug the image texture to the roughness, it all seems evenly glossy and ignores the image... My question is, How do I get the smooth areas to be a matte/brushed gold, and the embossed areas to be a shiny gloss gold?
[image]
adding the file! 
[image]

[image]

[image]
Below is an example of the types of finishes I would like.
[image]

Comment: Since your reference image shows metal , you'd like want to set *Metallic* to 1.0 and use a texture to control the roughness.

Comment: and a bit of anisotropic might help as well

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I did play with the Metallic, but for some reason when I give it a value it makes the surface a super flat dark brown color...any idea why?

Comment: Metal reflects environment. If the environment is black (no HDRI, no objects around), then the color of a metal surface is black.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is with your *Image Texture* node for your gloss map. Near the bottom of the node, change the *Colour Space* from *sRGB* to *Non-color Data.*

**Edit**

Your specular map is working properly. I checked by unplugged the normal map and looking at it. You seem to be having trouble getting your materials to look right, so I'm going to recommend that you watch the following two videos from BlenderGuru on how to create realistic materials. They're from pre 2.80, but it's still very helpful in understanding how all the settings affect your material.

[How to Make Photorealistic PBR Materials - Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V3wghbZ-Vh4)

[How to Make Photorealistic PBR Materials - Part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m1PkSViBi-M)

BlenderGuru also linked this Google Doc in those videos, which essentially contains real-life values for various materials, it's worth bookmarking.

[Physically Based Rendering Encyclopedia](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Fb9_KgCo0noxROKN4iT8ntTbx913e-t4Wc2nMRWPzNk/edit?usp=sharing)

PS: Part of getting reflective materials to look good is to have something to reflect...and not to have an overpowering *Light.001* hidden from the viewport.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this, but it doesn't seem to change anything. Do I need to use the alpha from the node for anything?

Comment: Mind uploading your blend file? Make sure you pack all the textures in btw. I can't really see why it isn't working from the screenshots.

Comment: Also, make sure the light isn't too powerful/close. Overexposing your object can overpower the specular map.

Comment: thank you @stphnl329 for the "pack all" suggestion. that was another first. Now I just need to figure out how to upload to the site. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi @blendernoob :). https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ is the preffered storage solution for this site. Just add the generated link to your original question.

Comment: thank you Jachym. I believe the link worked, and I added to the description of my post. Again, I apologize if I am missing simple things in my file! This is my first attempt at a material outside of a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

From your explanation, here is what I think will make it look the way you want.
[image]